# getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" in my-date-picker in angular ssr when running "ts-node:server"

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, universal

[image]

getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" in my-date-picker in angular ssr when running "ts-node:server".
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.7",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.6",

"compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ng2-admin:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "start:prerender": "ng serve --prerender",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build  --prerender",
    "serve:prerender": "node dist/server.js"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new version of the component: `angular-mydatepicker`

https://github.com/kekeh/angular-mydatepicker